# How to get array in php for show list page ionic2

Tags: php, arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have no idea to set and get array in my php

I want to show data in array from my php to list page

history.ts

```
getListHis(username){
                this.api.getListHis(this.username).subscribe(
                  data => {

                    this.mytext = data.text();

                    console.log(this.mytext);

                  },
                  err => console.error(err),
                  () => console.log('completed')
                  );
              }
```

history.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list >
      <ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let item of  mytext" >

        <h3> {{ item}}</h3>

      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and phpfile

```
$username = $_GET["username"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM history where user_log='".$username."'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$column = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $column[] = $row['his'];


}
$arrlength = count($column);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    echo $column[$x];

}

?>
```

> and $row['his']; = book,pencil
>
> but $column[$x]; = bookpencil

I try this above ,result is `console.log(this.mytext)` show `bookpencil` not array `book and pencil`

this cause get error

> Cannot find a differ supporting object 'bookpencil' of type 'string'. NgFor
>   only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: try `json_encode` and parse json.